# Send Data to new Intent via ListItem - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-activity

I have a lazy-list-like appearance using a SimpleAdapter which gets its data from a MySQL server online. On a ListItemClick, I want to send information to a new activity, which would use that data (say index number) to display specific results, again obtained from MySQL DB.

Since the list is dynamically generated, I need a way to send this dynamically generated data to a new activity.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You already set it, with an `intent`, you have to send this `intent` on the `onItemSelected` method of your `listview` listener.

Like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
i.putExtra(name, yourId);
startActivity(i);
```

and receive it like this in `onCreate` of the new `activity`

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras = i.getExtras();

if (extras != null) {
    int id = extras.getInt(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the arguments of `OnItemSelected` there's a thing called `long id` (last arg) here the id is the **`_id`** of the SqliteDB table you are using in SimpleCursorAdapter.

So as mentioned by @Leondros you use intents and using putExtra(), pass the information.

Here you will have to use parsing for converting **`long _id`** to string and then get it back at the receiving side of you intent.